# Tomcat7 deploy Fail: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component /w org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

Tags: spring-mvc, maven-3, tomcat7, web.xml, eclipse-juno

I have a very sample web.xml written below:

The problem is...If I remove **org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet** section, I can **successfully** deploy my project in Tomcat7 as a simple JSP-Servlet app. However, once I use Spring MVC, my deployment will *FAIL - Encountered exception org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/WebMVCProj2]]*

How can I fix this error?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    Spring Web MVC Application

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>HelloWorld</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/HelloServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- I can remove the part below to make deployment successful -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I add Spring MVC dependency from Enterprise Bundle Repository (EBR). I also use Eclipse Dynamic Web Module 3.0 which Tomcat7 should support. My jre is 1.6.x 64bits used by Tomcat and my project. I also use Web Deployment Assembly in Eclipse.

Here is my complete exception:

SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive E:\MyServers\apache-tomcat-7.0.30\webapps\WebMVCProj2.war
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/WebMVCProj2]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:963)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1600)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Comment: I wish I could post image to describe my project and war structure...to make my question more clear.

Comment: Have you created spring-servlet.xml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have applicationContext.xml  in web-inf folder or you have to define contextConfigLocation in your web.xml

```
<!-- Spring Context -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:/application-contexts/*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

It would be more helpful, if you could post exception trace.

Comment: thank you and I post my exception above. I have WEB-INF\ **spring-servlet.xml** for spring application context. Since <servlet-mapping> <servlet-name> **spring** </servlet-name>...in my Web.xml so I thought Spring would find my app context by default name **spring-servlet.xml** under WEB-INF folder.

Comment: Ok. Could you please let me know the "Caused by:" section of error stacktrace

Comment: It's been while since I finally figure out Spring needs an external dependency in my pom file.
`<dependency>
   <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.1</version>
  </dependency>` After I add this dependency, my web app can be deployed and run in Tomcat successfully.

Thank you again for your assistance. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can check your servlet class is having any annotation like **@WebServlet("**. I resolved the similar issue by removing the annotation in servlet class.